# What is this Amiga 2000 mod?

Tags: hardware, amiga-2000

I got an Amiga 2000, board Rev. 6 Does anyone know what is is?

> [image]
>   [image]
>   (click to enlarge)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not an aftermarket mod. As evidenced from numerous [pictures](https://oldcraporg.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/f0429376.jpg)  on the net.

Like:
A2000 Revision 6.3 Motherboard - on [Big Book of Amiga Hardware – Amiga Models & Clones / Commodore: A2000](https://www.bigbookofamigahardware.com/bboah/product.aspx?id=17)

> [image: A2000 Revision 6.3 Motherboard -]
>   [image]

As explained there:

> At the time, the Rev 4.x was in production, and the new board was desired for new production, as the price crossover from the 256K x 1 to the 256K x 4 memories had been reached. However, the Rev 5 board was completed ahead of the need for it. So the PCB guys did some additional cleanup work on the design, and I think the FCC people got involved, too. Regardless, the resulting Rev 6 motherboards were plagued with problems (in fairness, some were due to the switchover to a 68000 with faster signals, that was also noisier). - Dave Haynie

It's just a late time fix to get it shipping.

> [image]
>   –– From: Amiga A2000_R6 Rev.1.38 (05.09.2012) AmigaWiki [PDF](https://www.amigawiki.org/dnl/schematics/A2000_R6.pdf)

Some call it the ["funky bridge"](http://eab.abime.net/attachment.php?attachmentid=44062&d=1429905566) as explained in [Amiga 2000 Rev 6 to Rev 6.2 (or 6.3) hardware changes](http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=65570).

It appears to be

> Rev. 6.2: "Solder series connection of 68 Ohm and 270 pF to the very right of the 4 vias below CN303, other end of the circuit to ground. Eliminates power on Guru".
>   –– as documented here: [AmigaWiki A2000 Mainboard Upgrade](http://www.amigawiki.org/doku.php?id=de:service:upgrades:a2000_mainboard)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what is on the photo.